# Preformatted text in SSRS

Tags: text, reporting-services, format

How do I achieve the effect of preformated text in SSRS?

For example, this is what I see,

```
First Line of text
Second line of text
Third line of text
```

But I would like to see

```
First Line of text
   Second line of text
      Third line of text
```

The problem is obviously the leading spaces that I used in every line to indent the lines themselves. When those lines are rendered in SSRS (which is web based), the consecutive whitespaces are ignored.

Comment: Does using `&nbsp` explicitly help?

Comment: Hi NickyvV. Not at all. I tried to do that, but SSRS will strip it out the original string before being rendered. I also tried all other tricks in that direction, such as &emsp; and &ensp;. Also, inline CSS styles disapear when the page is rendered. Surprisingly enough, everything looks OK in the report preview in Visual Studio, but the problem appears when the report is rendered in the browser. The tag <pre> </pre> is also strip out